# What hardware specs do I need to run Apache/PHP and SVN?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, svn

I want to build a linux machine to use as a test server (LAMP) and use SVN on it.

I am thinking maybe Ubantu as the OS but what hardware specs would I need. I think the entire site is less than a gig but if SVN is going to keep multiple versions than wouldnt I need a huge hard drive?

Any tips would be nice.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's solely a dev/test server, you need next to nothing specs-wise. SVN will take up less space than you'd expect - it stores changes, not a new copy of the entire site for each revision.

Comment: So would like 160GB HDD, 1GB RAM, Celeron 2.26GHz CPU be good?

Comment: Most likely, yep.

Comment: Thanks, I would up-vote your answer but I don't have the rep to do so yet. It would be nice if all the SO sites combined your rep and was the same across the board!